# MongoDB Performance while reading and inserting from large txt files

Tags: mongodb, performance, io, server, virtual-machine

I'm inserting some documents into MongoDB by reading some txt files, extracting and decoding messages from them. Then, I insert the documents into a remote server related to a research center. I have many txt files and some of them are so large, more than 2 GB. The problem is that the process of inserting becomes slow after a while but if I try it with a smaller number of files and repeat it again and again it seems it's more faster.

And the questions:

1) How can I find if the problem is related to the MongoDB or my server (it's I/O for example)?

2) If I run two instances of my code at the same time, is it helping to accelerate the process or it makes the MongoDB server more slower and inefficient? (I think it makes MongoDB slow)

Sorry for long explanations, I wish you can reply, Thank you in advance for your help and support

Comment: Which code are you using to read those files...reading large files is an expensive operation, that's why it is always recommended to use the divide and conquer approach(divide your file into chunks of data)

Comment: I use my own code, it's like the other common ways to read the files inside a folder. Can you explain more?